# Can anyone identify this weed with jagged leaves and tiny white flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

Here is the image:

[image]

It grows in the Northeast USA in poor soil.  A bit invasive but pulls out easily.  I have an idea of what it is but would like confirmation.  Does not smell or taste herbaceous.

Comment: "or taste" I'm no plant expert, but I'd suggest not tasting plants you don't know the name of...there's some nasty stuff out there. ;)

Comment: Evidently also a common name of quickweed: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13418/what-is-this-annual-vegetable-garden-weed-with-minute-daisy-like-flowerheads/13431#13431

Answer (score 7):

It's Peruvian daisy (*Galinsoga quadriradiata*), which is native to Central and South America.

WRT its invasiveness, saith JK Small in 1933: "a particularly pestiferous weed of such rapid growth and seeding as to make eradication extremely difficult." Ok, then.

And WRT its edibility, Peruvian daisy is quite edible as a cooked green, and is a key ingredient in ajiaco, a Columbian chicken/potato/corn stew. So now you know what to make for your next potluck! (athough, there are related species, particularly *Tridax procumbens*, that supposedly are toxic, so perhaps you might be best taking it to a botanist at a local university just to be safe rather than trusting random ol' me. OTOH, I seriously doubt you would find a *Tridax* species anywhere in the continental US except for Florida).

Answer (score 4):

Very good information but I'm going to add some correction after much help from reddit.  It is Galinsoga Quadriradiata/Peruvian Daisy.  Good call on this.

There is another variety called Galinsoga Ciliata/Shaggy Soldier which is a bit hairy and has little to do with this conversation but interesting nonetheless.

The edible variety though is Galinsoga Parviflora/Gallant soldier/Guascas.

In any case, will attempt the ajiaco with dried substitution and very good suggestions from here, http://andreasrecipes.com/ajiaco-bogotano-colombia/

Thanks for the warning I just put a bit on my tongue.  Have identified spurge, nightshade and lily of the valley nearby so not trying to be reckless.

Comment: which subreddit is that from?