# What is this annual vegetable garden weed with minute daisy-like flowerheads?

Tags: identification, weeds

This plant grows in my vegetable gardens, and recently abandoned garden plots, but I haven't seen it at all on the rest of the property, including the landscaped beds. This indicates a preference to disturbed soil. It can root anywhere on the stem, and grow from cutting easily. It seems to have an indeterminate growth habit, flowering and seeding all year, until frost, which instantly kills it. It gets 10-24" high in my garden.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I dunno what it is, see if I can find out, but is that arrangement of petals on all of them, or has this close up example got some missing?

Comment: @Bamboo That is how all of them are. The ray flowers are evenly spaced, and usually come in fives, but don't often touch. They usually have 1-3 lobes each.

Comment: A little more detail and an alternate name of "Peruvian daisy" here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5171/can-anyone-identify-this-weed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I believe I've found it! [Quickweed, *Galinsoga quadriradiata*](http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=GAQU), in the sunflower family.